# how to get notified when download completed in FLEXIBLE in-app-update android?

Tags: android, in-app-update

I have tried below code for **FLEXIBLE** in-app-update android, and while click on Update in the dialog it starts downloading the new update from play-store in the background, I have added listener as **InstallStateUpdatedListener** but it will not notify me when the download has finished, also checked *onActivityResult()* but not worked.

how to get notified when background download has completed?

```
  AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;     
  int UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private void updateTheApp() {
   appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {

            Log.e("AVAILABLE_VERSION_CODE", appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode());
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {

                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                            MainActivity.this,
                            UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
    appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
}
```

Comment: how are you defining `installStateUpdatedListener`?

Answer (score 2):

```
appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
```

You are removing the listener immediately after you register it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check this and update you. If it is works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Create a listener which can listen to the background update,
After `state.installStatus()` state comes as downloaded `InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED` we have to mark the update complete as well.

```
InstallStateUpdatedListener listener = new InstallStateUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(InstallState state) {
            Log.d("installState", state.toString());
            if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                // After the update is downloaded, show a notification
                // and request user confirmation to restart the app.
                popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate();
            }
        }
    };
```

You can request InAppUpdate in your onCreate(), after Creating the Instance of

```
appUpdateManger = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
```

you can register the listener.

popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate() method,

```
private void popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate() {
        Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "An update has just been downloaded.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Restart", view -> appUpdateManager.completeUpdate());
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

After that work is done you have to unregister the listener as well.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("installState", "destroy");
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(listener);
    }
```